# Reuse an object as a type on JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to use an object that is defined within the constructor of a class as a type in functions within the class itself.

I wanted to do something like this so the autocomplete could work:

```js
class Collection {

  constructor(schema) {
    /**
     * @typedef {schema} Schema
     */

    // ...
  }

  /**
   * @param {Schema} searchObj
   */
  findOne(searchObj) {
    // ...
  }
```

This doesn't work as the value is dynamic, not static.

I would want to use the dynamic value "schema" in the constructor as a type, so when a user initialize the class, all the functions within the class could require a param with the same type as when initialized.

```js
const userCollection = new Collection({
  name: String,
  id: Number
})

userCollection.findOne({
  name: "AngelCMHxD" // This should have autocompletion
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, even using `@template`:

```
/** @template T */
class Collection {
    /**
     * @param {T} schema 
     */
    constructor(schema) {
    }
  
    /**
     * @param {T} searchObj 
     */
    findOne(searchObj) {
    }
}

// Collection<{
//     name: StringConstructor;
//     id: NumberConstructor;
// }>
const userCollection = new Collection({
    name: String,
    id: Number
})
  
userCollection.findOne({
    name: "AngelCMHxD" // expects StringConstructor, not string
})
```

since you passed `String` and `Number`, which are of types `StringConstructor` and `NumberConstructor`, respectively. If you wanted it to work, you would have to pass `""` and `0` so it's inferred as `string` and `number` instead:

```
// Collection<{ name: string; id: number }>
const userCollection = new Collection({
    name: "",
    id: 0
})
```

You should consider using TypeScript instead since its type system can easily represent this.